QField app. Project download stops at 22%
I have created a project on QFieldCloud, with about 25 collaborators with reporter rights. Some of them (about 50%) cannot download the project with the QField app on their mobiles. Download systematically stops at 22%.
Do you have any explanation/solution for this?

how long did you wait? I just had recently a similiar behaviour - the download was directly at 100% but did not finish for quite a while (~7minutes). Then suddenly it is finished and the project is available.

You have a very large layer? Do you have a base layer which the project is trying to load?
